# Silencing "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Unknown Module" error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I'm getting this error while debugging two background tasks that access an Entity Framework DB. Running just one background task does not seem to trigger the error message. I can't really tell what the issue is because everything is working fine except for the breaking error message that pops up during debug.

It would be great if I can find out why this is happening (the other questions related to this message are unsolved), but **the more important thing is turning the error notification off**. I am not sure why I am getting the error in the first place because  I do not have anything checked in my exception settings. Does anyone know how?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Tyress, you cannot turn off notifications for unhandled exceptions while debugging. Since unhandled exceptions typically result in application crashes, the debugger will always break when they are encountered.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @John , and that is unfortunate because I can't help but think that this is just some sort of Background Task bug (disabling DB access and most activities on the BG task will still get me the error)